# dynamic string substitution using string.Template in Python

Tags: python, string

Is it possible to do dynamic string substitution with Python's string.Template ? More precisely I don't want to replace occurrences of identifiers with results of functions, e.g.

```
from string import Template

f = lambda s: "123"

templateString = """first line: $replaceme
2nd line "$replaceme" """

s = Template(templateString).substitute(replaceme=f)
```

Instead of evaluating `f` its string representation is used:

```
first line: <function <lambda> at 0x7fb0367e3488>
2nd line "<function <lambda> at 0x7fb0367e3488>"
```

Any ideas how to do substitution with the result of `f` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `f` by doing `f()`.  `f` means the function; `f()` means its return value.

Comment: If using `f()` the evaluation is done once for all occurrences of `replaceme`. My intention was to call `f` for each occurrence.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster: Pretty sure that's not possible with the way you're doing it.  The placeholder in the template has to specify a static value, not an expression, so if you use `$replaceme` both times, you have to get the same value both times.